# How to fix MariaDB when it gets stuck during shutdown (Waiting for page_cleaner)?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mariadb, innodb

I am running MariaDB (v 10.3.13) on Arch Linux (Manjaro). It worked normally for the last months but now there are some issues. 
When I try to reboot the computer, it gets stuck at

```
A stop job is running for MariaDB 10.3.13 database server
```

The time it should take gets increased every minute till it finally times out (after approx 20 min).

Stopping MariaDB manually also gets stuck when I try to restart/stop it with

```
sudo systemctl stop/restart mariadb
```

Then running `sudo systemctl status mariadb` shows

```
/usr/bin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190402 20:31:01
InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
```

with every minute another line with `InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool` being added.

Is there a way to reset MariaDB? Or a way to get more information what the problem is?

PS: I installed some updates through the Package Manager lately, after which I noticed the issue for the first time.

**Update:**

When I uninstall, reboot and reinstall MariaDB, I can stop/restart MariaDB without issues and shutdown goes without issues. But after booting again, I am back to the above described problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a multiple hour long struggle, I could finally resolve the issue.

The culprit was a time setting (`timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`) for dual booting with Win10.

Due to a recent time change the clock was messed up. (The status log entries in `sudo systemctl status mariadb` were 1h in the future)

Setting

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

and rebooting resolved it.

Comment: Wow, thanks for sharing. Apparently I had the exact same issue. I just moved the clock a bit forward in time to resume :)) I'll move it back after it's done.

Comment: I don't have systemd ... so this does not work. :/

Answer (score 2):

Also you could change and reduce from `TimeoutSec=300`(5 minutes) to a lower timeout value from mysql start service config file:

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service

### after editing timout value in above config file you can apply it by using:
systemctl daemon-reload
```

**Note:** **This is not a fix** or solution for this problem. It just reduce service termination timeout value. You should consider finding a correct solution based on the situation or bug causing this happened on your OS and Service and reverting timeout to its default recommended value after issue is solved.

Comment: Which just kills the mysql server process, preventing a clean shutdown.

Comment: @GáborHéja true, but if no working solution, its a fast escape while stack is overflowing.

Comment: Yes it is, but it sounds important and I think should be in the answer. I edited it and removed my downvote. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @GáborHéja respectfully I will edit my answer according to your suggestion but unfortunatly I disagree with the exact note you suggest because the 5 minutes value was default value provided by mysql-service to terminate forcefully and my suggestion was to reduce it for shorter service timeouts. Here the situation is showing that there is a bug between OS and the Mysql-Service and that long time of termination is not doing any positiove actions (no difference if reduced) and could be just annoying on every restart. Still I agree this is not a solution but just an escape to be fixed later.

Comment: I have already edited but probably was discarded for some reason and my downvote was not removed, I fixed that now. In my case the InnoDB was doing a recovery that took way more than even 5 minutes so I think in some corner cases the note might be useful. Thanks for the responsiveness and being open to comments!